# Use side by side buttons instead of drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css

is it possible to replace a dropdown menu with three options to three side by side buttons? I've looked around online and can't seem to find anything similar.

below is my current setup.

[image]

This is what i want to replace the dropdown menu with. (bootstrap button group)

[image]

This is the current dropdown code.

```
  <div class="dropdown">

    <select id="selectMe">
        <option value="iPhone">iPhone</option>
        <option value="iPad">iPad</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    </select>




</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Josh.

The option is then passed on to a piece of java script this is where i'm having trouble simply switching the two.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.group').hide();
$('#iPhone').show();
$('#selectMe').change(function () {
$('.group').hide();
$('#'+$(this).val()).show();
})
});


</script>
```

Comment: What do you have now?  The answer is probably yes, but we need to see what you have, and what you want to accomplish (I did not downvote)

Comment: You should post the code you have and the attempts you have tried. In this way, it'll be much easier to get some help here.

Comment: Thank you @cale_b for providing feedback and not just clicking the down vote button like most. I have modified my question with my current setup

Comment: Writing up a dynamic js thing, gimme a moment

Comment: thank you i look forward to seeing it

Answer (score 2):

Sure, statically, with minor amounts of JS... but that's really just creating a radio button list in place of your DDL, then putting your own buttons that map to them via JS (hint: leverage `.previousElementSibling.checked`)- or, better yet, your own "buttons" that are actually just `label`s styled to *look* like buttons, and nix the need for JS entirely. I'll leave that solution to someone else to write up, because, alternatively....

Sure, dynamically, with -native- JS. Requires touching the DOM but tbh if you're afraid to touch the DOM, <insert generic insult here>.

Issues with this specific implementation...
 - Will break in browsers that don't support `dataset` ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)). To fix this problem, simply swap out the `dataset` in the hard-coded `onclick` on the buttons for the equivalent `.getAttribute()` call
 - Will break if something else adds an element below ddls after this runs
 - Creates the btns & radios manually rather than via `document.createElement`
 - onclick event hard-coded into the buttons rather than being a proper event trigger
 - reserves 2 class names (invocation, wrapper) and a pseudo-namespace in the `name` attribute
 - If you can just convert the dropdowns to radio+button lists in the actual HTML instead of doing it via javascript, this is kinda moot since you should do that instead.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cxbandh2/1/

Javascript:

```
(function(){
    //config
    var ddl_to_btns_class = 'ddl2btns';
    var wrapper_div_class = 'ddl2btn-wrapper';
    var radio_btn_name_prefix = '_ddl2btns$';

    //Personal pseudo-library functions
    //getElementByID
    function $(s, d) { return (d || document).getElementById(s); }
    //getElementsByClassName
    function $$(s, d) { return (d || document).getElementsByClassName(s); }
    //inserts an element as a younger sibling
    $.youngerSib = function (ele, sib) { ele.parentNode.insertBefore(sib, ele.nextSibling); }

    var ddls = $$(ddl_to_btns_class);
    for(var i = ddls.length>>>0; i--;){
        //generate our button list
        var optcnt = ddls[i].options.length >>> 0;
        var btns = new Array(optcnt);
        for(var j = optcnt; j--;){
            btns[j] = "<input type='radio' disabled hidden name='" + radio_btn_name_prefix + i +"' /><button type='button' data-ddlv='" + j + "' onclick='this.previousElementSibling.checked = true; this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.selectedIndex = parseInt(this.dataset.ddlv);'>" + ddls[i].options[j].text + "</button>";
        }

        //generate "widget"
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        wrapper.className = ddl_to_btns_wrapper_class;
        wrapper.innerHTML = btns.join('');

        //insert widget & hide ddl
        $.youngerSib(ddls[i], wrapper);
        ddls[i].hidden = true;
    }
})();
```

Sample HTML:

```
<select class="ddl2btns">
    <option>dog</option>
    <option>cat</option>
    <option>lizard</option>
</select>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.ddl2btn-wrapper > input:checked + button{
    background-color:#aaf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, with the current html it is not possible to have side by side buttons. Because it's not possible to style the `option` tags. It's rendered by the OS. [refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Except for `background-color` and `color`, style settings applied through
> the style object for the option element are ignored.

Though it is possible if you can edit the html. Then you'd change it as bootstrap suggests and it'll work just fine :)

Comment: Can't? Not true- like, at all. Hide the ddl and use js to both create the button list and map the buttons to the desired ddl values. I'd suggest using the js to do the hiding since noscript would then make the page unusable. The only thing you can't do with options is style something based on the selected value in a dropdown without using js. This is because we don't have a parent selector is CSS3. There's rumblings that CSS4 will have one.

Comment: Oh and if you need the buttons to be sticky, hide linked radio boxes in front of each button and use `.stickyRad + button` (or something similar) to style. Bonus, you'd only need to add a `this.previousElementSibling.checked = true;` to your onclick on the buttons.

Comment: The options and the values are available as HTML but not in css. So if you were to use js, you can re-render the entire damn thing :D But with the same html (js not touching the DOM), it's impossible to show the option information.

And the parent selector, it's been a while since it was proposed. Let's hope for the best

Comment: is there any chance you could point me in the right direction online or post some example code please? as don't understand how to do this

Comment: There's not really much of a reason to be afraid to touch the DOM, tbh. If that's causing you problems in layout or with other js, you should probably be looking at refactoring (or at least encapsulating your "widgets") to begin with.

Comment: @josh2205, I think this is what you're looking for http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills. Use the given in that nav-pills example. The styling problem will be fixed.

Comment: @abluejelly if you're editing the DOM, you can do it directly in the HTML than write a different HTML and then modify it using js

Comment: so how do i map the buttons to trigger the JS function instead of the dropdown box

Comment: @josh2205 With the new HTML there won't be any dropdown box, and for triggering the JS functions, you would need to learn some basics of `javascript` and 'DOM`. This is a good place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: @bigΩmega depending on the situation that might be either extremely inconvenient or not actually possible. However, you are correct that it would be better to just do the HTML as a radio+button list.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible. ONLY with bootstrap though. I'm not sure what you are using now but I can give you some good advice to get started..

If you don't know too much about bootstrap right now, don't sweat. It's pretty easy to pick up after awhile of practice. Read up on it a little bit, download a bootstrap template if you want, or start a blank application in VS (with bootstrap plugins of course) and start cracking away.

Here's a couple links to get ya started.
[Tutorial Republic guys are good](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/%22Tutorial%20Republic%20has%20great%20tuts%22)

[Here's another good link I used when I was getting started with BS](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889031/Bootstrap-for-Beginners)

Hope this helps!

Comment: False that it's only possible in Bootstrap. You can do it dynamically on-page via JS if you're not afraid of the DOM.